# Why does realloc fail on repeated calls where as allocating a big chunk using malloc works?

Tags: c, string, malloc, realloc

I am trying to read in from stdin (passing in value from a file). I am reading each character from the string and storing it into a dynamically allocated string pointer. When needed I realloc the memory. I am trying to get as many characters as possible. Though I can limit it to 100,000 chars. But the realloc fails after some iteration. But if I specify a chunk size big, say 1048567 during the first initialization in malloc, I am able to read the string completely. Why is this?

Below is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int display_mem_alloc_error();

enum {
    CHUNK_SIZE = 31    //31 fails. But 1048567 passes.
};

int display_mem_alloc_error() {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nError allocating memory");
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int numStr;                  //number of input strings
    int curSize = CHUNK_SIZE;    //currently allocated chunk size
    int i = 0;                   //counter
    int len = 0;                 //length of the current string
    int c;                       //will contain a character
    char *str = NULL;            //will contain the input string
    char *str_cp = NULL;         //will point to str
    char *str_tmp = NULL;        //used for realloc

    str = malloc(sizeof(*str) * CHUNK_SIZE);
    if (str == NULL) {
        display_mem_alloc_error();
    }    
    str_cp = str;   //store the reference to the allocated memory

    scanf("%d\n", &numStr);   //get the number of input strings
    while (i != numStr) {
        if (i >= 1) {   //reset
            str = str_cp;
            len = 0;
            curSize = CHUNK_SIZE;
        }
        c = getchar();
        while (c != '\n' && c != '\r') {
            *str = (char *) c;
            //printf("\nlen: %d -> *str: %c", len, *str);
            str = str + 1;
            len = len + 1;
            *str = '\0';
            c = getchar();
            if (curSize / len == 1) {
                curSize = curSize + CHUNK_SIZE;
                //printf("\nlen: %d", len);
                printf("\n%d \n", curSize);    //NB: If I comment this then the program simply exits. No message is displayed.
                str_tmp = realloc(str_cp, sizeof(*str_cp) * curSize);
                if (str_tmp == NULL) {
                    display_mem_alloc_error();
                }
                //printf("\nstr_tmp: %d", str_tmp);
                //printf("\nstr: %d", str);
                //printf("\nstr_cp: %d\n", str_cp);
                str_cp = str_tmp;
                str_tmp = NULL;
            }
        }
        i = i + 1;
        printf("\nlen: %d", len);
        //printf("\nEntered string: %s\n", str_cp);
    }
    str = str_cp;
    free(str_cp);
    free(str);
    str_cp = NULL;
    str = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Note that `sizeof (char)` is always 1, so adding using it in memory-allocation calls is generally considered a bad idea. It adds nothing (you multiply by 1) except noise for the humans reading the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you `realloc`

```
str_tmp = realloc(str_cp, sizeof(*str_cp) * curSize);
if (str_tmp == NULL) {
    display_mem_alloc_error();
}
//printf("\nstr_tmp: %d", str_tmp);
//printf("\nstr: %d", str);
//printf("\nstr_cp: %d\n", str_cp);
str_cp = str_tmp;
str_tmp = NULL;
```

you let `str_cp` point to the new block of memory, but `str` still points into the old, now `free`d block. Thus when you access what `str` points to in the next iteration, you invoke undefined behaviour.

You need to save the offset of `str` with respect to `str_cp`, and after the reallocation, let`str` point into the new block at its old offset.

And `*str = (char *) c;` is wrong, although there is a nonzero chance of it being functionally equivalent to the correct `*str = c;`.

Comment: After the `str_cp = str_tmp;` I added `str = str_cp + len;` as you mentioned and the program works perfectly. Wow! Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

```
     *str = (char *) c;
```

This line is wrong.

`str` is a pointer to `char` and `*str` is a `char` but you are assigning a pointer to `char` to a `char`. This cannot be done in C.

Moreover:

```
scanf("%d\n", &numStr);
```

The `\n` in `scanf` call probably does not what you expect:

http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfhang.html

And also:

```
str = str_cp;
free(str_cp);
free(str);
```

You have a double free here. After the assignment `str` and `str_cp` will have the same value so doing:

```
free(str_cp);
free(str);
```

is as if you do:

```
free(str);
free(str);
```

which is undefined behavior (you cannot free twice).

Comment: Isn't `*s = 'a'`; correct? I am dereferencing the pointer and saving the value to the place pointed by the s, right? In the above case, since c is an int, I am converting it into char, no? Isn't it same as say `s[0] = (char*)c;` ?

Comment: @kadaj No. You seem to think that the asterisk on the right hand side doesn't matter, but it does! A cast to `(char)` is not the same as a cast to `(char *)`. The former is "character", the latter is "pointer to character". Casting an `int` to a pointer is very often not the right thing to do.

Comment: Oh! Using (char) is okay, right? But the program http://pastebin.com/Gd0Nyv0z seems to work. But that might be undefined behavior. I get that casting mistake.